# Условие для скрипта на JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

Работаю с JavaScript, возникла проблема.
Вот например, в PHP так:

```
if (($_GET[q]))
{
    echo 'yes';
}  else {
    echo 'undefined';    
}
```

Как эту функцию написать в JavaScript?
Нужно чтобы если такой запрос в URL:

```
/?q=тут текст
```

Срабатывает функция в JavaScript файле:

```
    googleSearch();
    return false;
```

Например, я использую такой вариант, если нажать на ссылку:

```
<a href="#" id="test" onclick="$('#s').focus().val(this.innerHTML);return false;">PHP</a>
```

происходит следующее:

```
$('#test').click(function(){
  googleSearch();
  return false;
});
```

а нужно, чтобы при условии того, если в `/?q=` есть текст срабатывает **googleSearch()**,  если нет, то ничего не происходит и нужно чтобы `googleSearch()` сработал один раз.

Comment: Текущий URL можно получить через 

     var url = document.location.href;

Если же /?q это все-таки поле формы, то ему нужно присвоить ID и воспользоваться 

    var obj = document.getElementById('id');
    var q = obj.value;

Comment: у вас и в php неправильно, empty или isset надо применить

Comment: @eicto, пока учусь :) 
@Silver и тут у меня ничего не выходит, готовый код написал ниже, в комментариях к ответу Deonisю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы проверяете URI из адресной строки, то можно так:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

if(getUrlVars()['q']){
    alert('Гуд!');
}
```

Если при клике по ссылке, проверить атрибут href и присутствие параметра **q**, то делаем маленькие изменения:

```
function getUrlVars(uri) {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = uri.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
$('#test').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = getUrlVars($(this).attr('href'))['q'];
    if(param){
        alert('Гуд! Значение параметра: ' + param);
    }
});
```

[Смотреть работу скрипта](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/GpxKg/).

Comment: @Deonis, Спасибо, но эти функции не есть ответ для меня, у меня совсем другая задача. Обратите пожалуйста внимания на этот код:

    document.getElementById('s').value = window.location.search.split('?q=')[1] || '';

и вот, при условии, что если в /?q=  есть текст, срабатывает GoogleSerch();  а проблема в том, что я не знаю как это все написать в javascript, головой не получается. Прошу Вас показать или объяснить подробный алгоритм

Comment: @Deonis, что то я не совсем ваш код понял...  
Можете объяснить: что делает функция переданная в String.replace или это новая feature от JQuery?